# How to validate object values in a List if value is not empty or not null using java 8 stream

Tags: java, list, iterator, java-stream

I have an objectList

```
    OfferToCheck offer = new OfferToCheck();
    
    offer.setDiscountId(null);
    offer.setProductName("sadf spacefjkd");
    offer.setServiceCode("dfsdfv");
    offer.setServiceGroup("nospace");

    OfferToCheck offer1 = new OfferToCheck();
    offer1.setDiscountId("");
    offer1.setProductName("sadfspacefjkd");
    offer1.setServiceCode("sdnof");
    offer1.setServiceGroup("sdf");
    
    request.setOffersToCheck(Arrays.asList(offer,offer1));      
    request.setStartTrialPeriod("y");
if(service.validateStatus(request)){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

i want to acheive this for loop using java 8 stream

```
for(OfferToCheck offer : request.getOffersToCheck()){
        if(offer.getDiscountId() != null && !offer.getProductName().isEmpty()){
            if(!offer.getDiscountId().chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)){
                return isValid = false;
            }
            
        }
        if(offer.getServiceCode() != null && !offer.getServiceCode().isEmpty()){
            if(!offer.getServiceCode().chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic)){
                return isValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(offer.getServiceGroup() != null && !offer.getServiceGroup().isEmpty()){
            if(!offer.getServiceGroup().chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic)){
                return isValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(offer.getProductName() != null && !offer.getProductName().isEmpty()){
            if(!offer.getProductName().matches("[a-zA-Z ]*")){
                return isValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this but when value of discountId is empty or null it does not include the rest of the object into the stream.

```
    if(!request.getOffersToCheck().stream()
              .filter(list -> (list.getServiceCode() != null && !list.getServiceCode().isEmpty()))
              .filter  (list -> list.getDiscountId() != null && !list.getDiscountId().isEmpty()) 
              .filter  (list -> list.getProductName() != null && !list.getProductName().isEmpty())
              .filter (list -> list.getProductName() != null && !list.getProductName().isEmpty()) 
              .filter (list -> list.getServiceGroup() != null && !list.getServiceGroup().isEmpty())
              .allMatch(validateList -> (validateList .getDiscountId().chars().allMatch(Character::isLetterOrDigit)
                      && validateList.getProductName().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*")
                      && validateList.getServiceCode().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
                      && validateList.getServiceGroup().chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit))
                      ))
    {
        return isValid = false;
    }
```

also tried all the condtion in one filter

Comment: While writing my answer, I feel you have a typo: `if(offer.getDiscountId() != null && !offer.getProductName().isEmpty()){` should be `if(offer.getDiscountId() != null && !offer.getDiscountId().isEmpty()){` in the 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map of the field mappings (using `Function`) as a key and a `Predicate` as a value of the field validation itself.

Then all you need is to iterate through the offers (`Stream<OfferToCheck>`) and for each one iterate through the map which represents both the extraction and the validation itself.

- Using it's key you extract the field value (i.e. `String fieldValue = entry.getKey().apply(offer)`)
- Using it's value you validate the field value (i.e. `entry.getValue().test(fieldValue)`)

You want to collect all the `boolean` results from `Stream::allMatch` and get sure they are all true, thus returning that result itself.

```
Map<Function<OfferToCheck, String>, Predicate<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(OfferToCheck::getDiscountId, s -> s.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit));
map.put(OfferToCheck::getServiceCode, s -> s.chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic));
map.put(OfferToCheck::getServiceGroup, s -> s.chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic));
map.put(OfferToCheck::getProductName, s -> s.matches("[a-zA-Z ]*"));

return request.getOffersToCheck()
     .stream()
     .allMatch(offer -> map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().apply(offer) != null && 
                              !entry.getKey().apply(offer).isEmpty())
              .allMatch(entry -> entry.getValue().test(entry.getKey().apply(offer))));
```

This solution assumes all the fields are validated in the similar way - ex. `String::isEmpty` is used. Otherwise you have to place such validation to the map and remove it from the inner Stream. Feel free to modify the code according to your needs.

The final choice whether you are up to this solution is solely up to you:

**Pros**

- Useful for a large number of similar field validations, ex. SOAP.
- Scalable: the only thing you add with each new field is a new `map` entry.

**Cons**

- Harder to read, maintain and debug (you have to use `Stream::peek`).
- Needs proper unit tests to cover such logic (I'd recommend you anyway, this implementation implies a strong need for a test).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it means it's not always a good idea to use stream.

Comment: Exactly! I think you can make a decision based on the cons/pros I have described - it applies for this particular case.